# Instruments fails within 2 seconds of starting

Tags: xcode, ipad, instruments

App isn't crashing, it keeps going fine. Seems to happen right as the app actually shows something on the screen. This is the error from Xcode:

> Failed to start Instruments daemon for
>   'iOS' on 'Michael’s iPad (v4.3.1)'
>   ((null))
>
> Please reconnect the device.

This is what the device console says:

> May 16 17:54:58 unknown lockdownd[17]
>   : 01237000 handle_connection:
>   Could not receive USB message #22 from
>   Instruments. Killing connection May 16
>   17:54:58 unknown
>   com.apple.mobile.lockdown[17]
>   : receive secure message
>   timeout!

No idea what's going on here, I've tried deleting all the provisioning profiles off of my device as well as removing it from being a device used for development.

Comment: have you tried rebooting the device and computer?

Comment: yeah, :shrug: might as well try again (haven't done both at the same time). will comment again if it fixed it.

Comment: no go, very slightly different error: Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'Michael’s iPad (v4.3.1)' (SessionInactive)

Please reconnect the device.

Comment: that's really strange. not quite sure what the problem is...

Comment: Update: on further exploration I noticed that this only seems to happen on ipad 2.

Comment: no, It happens in my iPhone 3Gs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153098/unable-to-connect-iphone-3gsios-5-0-1-with-instruments-application

Answer (score 1):

That Happen with Instruments.Apple not much emphasize on instruments.But I faced same problem as you face right now.I have same code for iphone and ipad but instruments is only running with iphone not ipad.After Lot's effort,I figured out that my iphone ios was 4.3.1 and ipad was is 4.3.5 and then i tried this code with ipad ios 4.3.1 and instrument was run successful.