# Unable to connect iPhone 3gs(iOS 5.0.1) with Instruments application

Tags: ios5, instruments, iphone-3gs

When i am connecting my 3gs(iOS 5.0.1) device to Instruments i am getting this error message

```
" Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on  iPhone 3GS (v5.0.1)' (The service is invalid.)

Please reconnect the device."
```

This message appears on instruments, when ever i re-connect the device. How can i do performance testing with this device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea what is causing this - but i did find a solution that worked on both devices that caused instruments pop out this message - making them unusable.
I simply started Xcode's Organizer, and after Organizer reading the devices' data - both worked with instruments flawlessly.

Comment: thx, strangely instruments stopped working today, it was all good yesterday and I didnt change anything, your solution worked

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to do the same thing from the command line? Something needs to be reset on the phone or in the connected Mac and if we can do this from the command line then we can reliably run automated tests on a build server.

Answer (score 7):

I received this error message while trying to run Instruments with an iPod 4G connected. It turned out that I was using an out-of-date version of Instruments from an earlier version of XCode (4.2). (When I searched for Instruments in Spotlight, only this version appeared because later versions of XCode hide their tools inside the XCode.app package.) Your circumstances may be different but I suspect that you did not run Instruments from the Profile command in the XCode IDE.

To verify if this is the problem, check the version of Instruments (in 'About Instruments') and verify that it is the same version as your XCode IDE. (For me, these were 4.2 and 4.5 respectively.) If they do not match, right-click on the XCode app in your Applications folder and select 'Show Package Contents'. In Contents/Applications, you should find the correct version of Instruments.

Comment: this is exactly what my problem. thank you for sharing your post. it helped me a lot. cheers JMcF

Comment: thanks man, this was precisely it for me. out of date bookmark on the dock. I'll add this to my list of wonky crap that Instruments does.

Answer (score 4):

I received this error message while trying to run instruments on with iPhone4s and 3GS.
To resolve that issue I open the Xcode than select select the windows>organizer select the device and clear the Consol and device logs.
After above steps instruments have detected the device.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning the Console worked for me :)

I was automating a Hybrid app.

I did these:

- Opened Xcode
- Goto Window
- Organizer
- Under you device name goto Console.
- Clear the the console.

Hope this helps some one.