# fail to start instruments with iOS6

Tags: xcode, instruments, ios6

I am developing app on iOS6.0 with Xcode3.2.5.
As I have copy the iPhoneOS6.0.sdk and DeviceSupport/6.0 to Developer directory,I can install and run app with Xcode.
But I failed to run app with Instruments whether launching from Xcode or directly double-click the Instruments app.
The error message is:

> Device Connection Failed
>
> Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'iPod007(v6.0)'((null))
>
> Please reconnect the device.

I get the same message after reconnect the device.

Comment: I guess recommending to upgrade your Xcode to a version that is not outdated since more than a year wont be an option then?

Comment: I am using Max OS X Snow leapord, so I only can upgrade to XCode4.2. and launching Instruments4.2 is failed too.

Comment: Check this answers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153098/unable-to-connect-iphone-3gsios-5-0-1-with-instruments-application

Answer (score 13):

I has same problem because there are many instrument on my MAC. So, I did run an old verion.

By this way, you can run newest version.

Open newest Xcode --> Xcode menu --> Open developer tools --> Instruments

Or see pic at here

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: I had an older version of Instruments in my dock, so all I did was Open Developer Tools > Instruments and then dock this new version that is included with XCode v4.6 and it saw my iPad 4.  Simple and effective!